# my template is not being parsed

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
angular.module('dodgie', []).config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider.when('/home', {template:'/partials/home.html', controller:dodgieCtrl   }).
      otherwise({redirectTo:'/home'});
});

function dodgieCtrl($scope, $location){
    $scope.doSearch = function(){
        if ( !$scope.newTodo.length ) {
          return;
        }
    };
};
```

The content of :

```
<div id="content" ng-view></div>
```

is instead:

```
 <span class="ng-scope">/partials/home.html</span>
```

why isn't my partials being rendered?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like a typo try `templateUrl` instead of `template`:

```
angular.module('dodgie', []).config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider.when('/home', {templateUrl:'/partials/home.html', controller:dodgieCtrl   }).
      otherwise({redirectTo:'/home'});
});
```

Taken from the [docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24routeProvider):

- template – {string=} – html template as a string that should be used by ngView or ngInclude directives. this property takes precedence over templateUrl.
- templateUrl – {string=} – path to an html template that should be used by ngView.

Comment: This bit me in the last few weeks, too! The change came in 1.0.0rc11.

Answer (score 1):

Use 'templateUrl' instead of 'template' if you intend to specify url.